# Cucumber Java (Maven) - FileInputStream - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, webdriver-manager

Hi people: I'm facing the next issue in Cucumber with Maven/Selenium/Java

```
Given I go to Google                                  # Step_First.I_go_to_Google()
      java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at pages.Page_First.getURL(Page_First.java:38)
    at stepdefs.Step_First.I_go_to_Google(Step_First.java:22)
    at ✽.I go to Google (src/test/java/features/first.feature:8)

    When I query for "<search>" cucumber spring selenium        # Step_First.I_query_for_cucumber_spring_selenium(String)
    And click search                                            # Step_First.click_search()
    Then google page title should become the first page         # Step_First.google_page_title_should_become_the_first_page()

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:130)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at pages.Page_First.getURL(Page_First.java:38)
    at stepdefs.Step_First.I_go_to_Google(Step_First.java:22)
    at ✽.I go to Google (src/test/java/features/first.feature:8)
```

This is my **feature** file:

```
Feature: Navigation Test


  Scenario: Search google.com to verify google search is working

    Given I go to Google
    When I query for "<search>" cucumber spring selenium
    And click search
    Then google page title should become the first page
```

This is the **Page** method that I use:

```
public void getURL() throws IOException {

        Properties Config = new Properties();

        //Declares a variable for reading properties from a resource bundle file (*.properties)
        Properties p = new Properties();

        //Always the Absolute path here.
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/automation_projects/" +
                "zero/src/main/resources/data/config.properties"));
        Config.load(file);

        driver.get(Config.getProperty("url"));

        //The String inside the config.properties
        String url = p.getProperty("url");
    }
```

In my **step definition** file I have this:

```
@Given("I go to Google")
    public void I_go_to_Google () throws IOException {

        page_first.getURL();
    }
```

Reviewing the information above, the issue occurs in this line:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/automation_projects/" +
                "zero/src/main/resources/data/config.properties"));
```

By the way, my **config.properties** file:

```
browser = firefox
url = https://www.google.com
```

May anybody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the property file really, really at the that location?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have modified the path to: src/main/resources/data/config.properties, but the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried only using the file path without the call to System.getProperty ? I doubt you have a property with a key being a file name

Comment: I did it, but the result is the same. Actually it is reading the data from properties. The case is that is not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/automation_projects/" +
            "zero/src/main/resources/data/config.properties"));
```

you try to look up a system property *actually named* `/Users/xxxxx/..../config.properties` which most likely doesn't exist, which therefore returns `null` which is then uncritically used as an argument to `new FileInputStream(null)` which then immediately fails.

Your understanding of how `System.getProperty` works is incorrect.  Consider reading in a `Properties` file from that location and then work with that.

Comment: Then your code in the posting is not current. Please consider the time of others when asking here.

Comment: I don't know what you mean: If you see above
            "zero/src/main/resources/data/config.properties")); you can see that the information comes from the config.properties

Comment: What do you think that `System.getProperty("/Users/xxxxxx/Documents/automation_projects/" +
            "zero/src/main/resources/data/config.properties")` does?